# Chart.js sets canvas dimentions to 0x0 and do not display anything

Tags: angular, chart.js

I got the first char.js example from official docs and tried to implement it with angular. No errors, chart object is created normally but nothing is displayed. When I examine DOM in devtools I see that chart.js set width/height of canvas to 0. What I did wrong?

The code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-ex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chart is not visible because the component host is an `inline` element. As such, it should not contain block elements like the `div` wrapper created by the `Chart.js` library.

Setting the `display` style attribute of the host to `block` or `inline-block` will make the chart visible:

```
:host {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-ex-zhelo2?file=src/app/app.component.css) for a demo.